Risks of restoring old books from decaying
I was reading this article on "
Why Do Old Books Smell So Good?" and I came across a part of it that seemed to be not elaborated upon.

Rapidly degrading and at-risk documents that are identified by degradomics can be treated or neutralized in large reactors to balance their acidity and slow the decay.

(These papers are mass produced with mainly rosin (a pine tar resin), bleached pulp, groundweed, and rag fiber)
I wanted an insight on the chemical mechanisms behind these neutralisation treatments used to balance the acidity and slow down the decay of paper. Specifically, are there any potential side effects or long-term consequences associated with using specific chemicals for neutralization treatments on paper? For instance, could they alter the paper's physical properties (strength, flexibility),  change its visual appearance (color, opacity), or introduce new risks of future degradation or alteration of the texts? (Specific examples of techniques for specific types of paper would be appreciated; however, I am looking at rosin based paper mainly) Or is it simply to early to conclude anything. Thank you.

related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33823/what-causes-the-old-book-smell

As mentioned in the article(that I linked), the books were made between 1850 and 1990, and they were made of rosin (a pine tar resin), bleached pulp, groundweed, and rag fiber.

slightly related: How does a photochemical reaction of lignin with oxygen (yellowing of paper) produce chromophores?

The biggest threat to old documents is caused by acid-driven decomposition of the cellulosic structure of paper, various chemical methods can stop this
Why paper degrades
Before considering the various methods that can preserve paper, it is worth understanding the mechanisms of degradation.
Paper is usually made from a bed of cellulose fibres made from a variety of sources. Very old documents are often made of rag paper created from cotton or linen clothing. This paper tends to be of high quality and the cellulose fibres are very long. But the paper is expensive to make. Modern paper is mostly made from wood pulp. Chemically treated wood pulp gives paper with medium-length cellulose fibres but cheap paper (like newspring) is made from mechanically pulped paper which gives much shorter fibres.
A big long term threat to the structure of paper is acid-catalysed degradation of the cellulose fibres. This is auto-catalytic as the degradation itself generates more acid, speeding the rate. There is a good summary of the issues here.
The process used for newsprint also leaves undesirable components in the paper like lignin (which promoted degradation). And much paper produced before 1980 used alum rosin-based sizing/fixing additives which tend to produce sulfuric acid in the presence of moisture furthering degradation. Some atmospheric pollutants also contribute to acid degradation (hence why many old books go brown on the exposed edges.)
Since the 1980s many producers started to include alkaline buffers to limit this effect by neutralising any acid.
Modern preservation methods
Because of the need to protect old documents and archives which were often not printed on long-life paper, chemists have proposed a variety of methods to protect and preserve existing documents. Most involve solving the problem of acid neutralisation but a few also try to to structurally strengthen the paper.
One interesting early process involved impregnating documents with gaseous organometallic Diethyl Zinc. This reacts with any moisture or acids in the paper to form insoluble zinc hydroxide which then acts as an alkaline buffer against further attack. This worked well but was abandoned as the practicalities of working with the dangerously pyrophoric organometallic turned out to be a little too risky.
Something similar in principle can be achieved by soaking the paper with various alkali suspensions in water (but they tend to work best for single sheets and the use of water can be a problem).
Alternative non-aqueous ways of neutralising acid contaminants have been further pursued. For example, Rheinmetall reports that the Swiss government has a large plant where a solution of titanium and magnesium alcoholates can perform a similar role to the diethylzinc when a solution of them in hexamethydisiloxane is used to deliver them to documents.
Other mixes of chemicals have also been used, mostly with the same general principles.
One additional method that has been used to strengthen the structure of paper for the long term has been to embed the paper with volatile methacrylate monomers which are then polymerised in situ.
And these are just some of the better-known methods. Most involve some attempt to prevent future acid-driven cellulose degradation. But without damaging the structure of the paper or causing problems causing the ink to blur.

With regards to dialkylzincs, we're fortunate (?) to have a relevant TIWWW.

Old books are slowly decaying because of cellulose being slowly attacked by acids present in the paper. This can be avoided by putting sodium bicarbonate on the successive pages, and brushing this away later on. This acidic destruction can also be done by using vapors of diethylzinc.

Indeed. But what are the implications of this? Could it possibly alter the paper's physical properties (strength, flexibility), change its visual appearance (color, opacity), or introduce new risks of future degradation or alteration of the texts. Do you have any specific examples of these implications?

No. The color and opacity is not modified by bicarbonate or vapors of diethyl zinc. New risks of future degradation are not known.
